# cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory

Tags: bazel

I got this error while cross-compile for aarch64. while compile i got error: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory. but this object is exist.

below is my bazel config.

### BUILD

this is `BUILD` file

```
load(":cc_toolchain_config.bzl", "cc_toolchain_config")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

filegroup(name = "empty")

filegroup(
    name = "all",
    srcs = glob([
        "**",
    ]),
)

cc_toolchain_config(name = "s32g_toolchain_config")

cc_toolchain(
    name = "s32g_toolchain",
    all_files = ":all",
    compiler_files = ":all",
    dwp_files = ":all",
    linker_files = ":all",
    objcopy_files = ":all",
    strip_files = ":all",
    toolchain_config = ":s32g_toolchain_config",
    toolchain_identifier = "s32g-toolchain",
)

toolchain_type(name = "toolchain_type")

toolchain(
    name = "aarch64_linux_toolchain",
    exec_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:aarch64",
    ],
    toolchain = ":s32g_toolchain",
    toolchain_type = "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type",
)
```

### cc_toolchain_config.bzl

this is `cc_toolchain_config.bzl`

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/cc:action_names.bzl", "ACTION_NAMES")
load(
    "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:cc_toolchain_config_lib.bzl",
    "feature",
    "flag_group",
    "flag_set",
    "tool_path",
)

all_link_actions = [
    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_executable,
    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_dynamic_library,
    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_nodeps_dynamic_library,
]

all_compile_actions = [
    ACTION_NAMES.assemble,
    ACTION_NAMES.c_compile,
    ACTION_NAMES.clif_match,
    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_compile,
    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_header_parsing,
    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_module_codegen,
    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_module_compile,
    ACTION_NAMES.linkstamp_compile,
    ACTION_NAMES.lto_backend,
    ACTION_NAMES.preprocess_assemble,
]

def _impl(ctx):
    tool_paths = [
        tool_path(
            name = "ar",
            path = "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fsl-linux/aarch64-fsl-linux-ar",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "cpp",
            path = "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fsl-linux/aarch64-fsl-linux-cpp",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "gcc",
            path = "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fsl-linux/aarch64-fsl-linux-gcc",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "gcov",
            path = "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fsl-linux/aarch64-fsl-linux-gcov",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "ld",
            path = "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fsl-linux/aarch64-fsl-linux-ld",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "nm",
            path = "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fsl-linux/aarch64-fsl-linux-nm",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "objdump",
            path = "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fsl-linux/aarch64-fsl-linux-objdump",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "strip",
            path = "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fsl-linux/aarch64-fsl-linux-strip",
        ),
    ]

    default_compiler_flags = feature(
        name = "default_compiler_flags",
        enabled = True,
        flag_sets = [
            flag_set(
                actions = all_compile_actions,
                flag_groups = [
                    flag_group(
                        flags = [
                            "--sysroot=/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux",
                            "-no-canonical-prefixes",
                            "-fno-canonical-system-headers",
                            "-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined",
                        ],
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ],
    )

    default_linker_flags = feature(
        name = "default_linker_flags",
        enabled = True,
        flag_sets = [
            flag_set(
                actions = all_link_actions,
                flag_groups = ([
                    flag_group(
                        flags = [
                            "-L/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux",
                            "-L/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/lib",
                            "-L/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/usr/lib",
                            "-L/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-fsl-linux/10.2.0",
                        ],
                    ),
                ]),
            ),
        ],
    )

    features = [
        default_compiler_flags,
        default_linker_flags,
    ]

    return cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info(
        ctx = ctx,
        cxx_builtin_include_directories = [
            "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/usr/include",
            "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/10.2.0",
            "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/10.2.0/include",
        ],
        features = features,
        toolchain_identifier = "s32g-toolchain",
        host_system_name = "local",
        target_system_name = "unknown",
        target_cpu = "unknown",
        target_libc = "unknown",
        compiler = "unknown",
        abi_version = "unknown",
        abi_libc_version = "unknown",
        tool_paths = tool_paths,
    )

cc_toolchain_config = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {},
    provides = [CcToolchainConfigInfo],
)
```

### error info

this is the error info.

```
Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/10.2.0/real-ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/10.2.0/real-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/10.2.0/real-ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
```

according to this link `https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3844`.

maybe I should declare those objects in cc_toolchain, but I do not understand how to declare them.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix it. just set `builtin_sysroot`

```
return cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info(
        ctx = ctx,
        cxx_builtin_include_directories = [
            "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/usr/include",
            "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/10.2.0",
            "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-fslbsp-linux/usr/lib/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/10.2.0/include",
        ],
        features = features,
        toolchain_identifier = "s32g-toolchain",
        host_system_name = "local",
        target_system_name = "unknown",
        target_cpu = "unknown",
        target_libc = "unknown",
        compiler = "unknown",
        abi_version = "unknown",
        abi_libc_version = "unknown",
        tool_paths = tool_paths,
        builtin_sysroot = "/opt/xcu-fsl-auto/1.0/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux",
    )
```